# Google Maps Clearing All Markers and Polylines

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polyline, google-polyline

I have a function that sets routes on a map this function creates polylines from start to destination. Once the ploylines have been drawn i then animate markers along these paths.

When a marker has been animated along a polyline and has reached its destination i would like to clear all overlays from the map.

Here is a [LINK](http://jsbin.com/eHayUla/1/edit?html,output) of what i have thus far.

How can this be accomplished?

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Complex</title>


<style>
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;margin:0px;font-family: Helvetica,Arial;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/v3_epoly.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map;
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService;
  var stepDisplay;

  var position;
  var marker = [];
  var polyline = [];
  var poly2 = [];
  var poly = null;
  var startLocation = [];
  var endLocation = [];
  var timerHandle = [];


  var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
  var infowindow = null;

  var myPano;   
  var panoClient;
  var nextPanoId;

  var startLoc = new Array();
  startLoc[0] = 'rio claro, trinidad';
  startLoc[1] = 'preysal, trinidad';
  startLoc[2] = 'san fernando, trinidad';
  startLoc[3] = 'couva, trinidad';

  var endLoc = new Array();
  endLoc[0] = 'princes town, trinidad';
  endLoc[1] = 'tabaquite, trinidad';
  endLoc[2] = 'mayaro, trinidad';
  endLoc[3] = 'arima, trinidad';


  var Colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];


function initialize() {  

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    { 
      size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
    });

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    address = 'Trinidad and Tobago'
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
     map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);

    }); 
  // setRoutes();
  } 


function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
// alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        marker.myname = label;


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    return marker;
}  

function setRoutes(){   

    var directionsDisplay = new Array();

    for (var i=0; i< startLoc.length; i++){

    var rendererOptions = {
        map: map,
        suppressMarkers : true,
        preserveViewport: true
    }
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;  

    var request = {
        origin: startLoc[i],
        destination: endLoc[i],
        travelMode: travelMode
    };  

        directionsService.route(request,makeRouteCallback(i,directionsDisplay[i]));

    }   


    function makeRouteCallback(routeNum,disp){
        if (polyline[routeNum] && (polyline[routeNum].getMap() != null)) {
         startAnimation(routeNum);
         return;
        }
        return function(response, status){

          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var route = response.routes[0];
            startLocation[routeNum] = new Object();
            endLocation[routeNum] = new Object();


            polyline[routeNum] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
            strokeWeight: 3
            });

            poly2[routeNum] = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
            strokeWeight: 3
            });     


            // For each route, display summary information.
            var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;


            disp = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);     
            disp.setMap(map);
            disp.setDirections(response);


            //Markers               
            for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
              if (i == 0) { 
                startLocation[routeNum].latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                startLocation[routeNum].address = legs[i].start_address;
                // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
                marker[routeNum] = createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
              }
              endLocation[routeNum].latlng = legs[i].end_location;
              endLocation[routeNum].address = legs[i].end_address;
              var steps = legs[i].steps;

              for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;                
                var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

                for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
                    polyline[routeNum].getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                    //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                }

              }
            }

         }       

         polyline[routeNum].setMap(map);
         //map.fitBounds(bounds);
         startAnimation(routeNum);  

    } // else alert("Directions request failed: "+status);

  }

}

    var lastVertex = 1;
    var stepnum=0;
    var step = 50; // 5; // metres
    var tick = 100; // milliseconds
    var eol= [];
//----------------------------------------------------------------------                
 function updatePoly(i,d) {
 // Spawn a new polyline every 20 vertices, because updating a 100-vertex poly is too slow
    if (poly2[i].getPath().getLength() > 20) {
          poly2[i]=new google.maps.Polyline([polyline[i].getPath().getAt(lastVertex-1)]);
          // map.addOverlay(poly2)
        }

    if (polyline[i].GetIndexAtDistance(d) < lastVertex+2) {
        if (poly2[i].getPath().getLength()>1) {
            poly2[i].getPath().removeAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength()-1)
        }
            poly2[i].getPath().insertAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength(),polyline[i].GetPointAtDistance(d));
    } else {
        poly2[i].getPath().insertAt(poly2[i].getPath().getLength(),endLocation[i].latlng);
    }
 }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

function animate(index,d) {
   if (d>eol[index]) {

      marker[index].setPosition(endLocation[index].latlng);
      return;
   }
    var p = polyline[index].GetPointAtDistance(d);

    //map.panTo(p);
    marker[index].setPosition(p);
    updatePoly(index,d);
    timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+","+(d+step)+")", tick);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

function startAnimation(index) {
        if (timerHandle[index]) clearTimeout(timerHandle[index]);
        eol[index]=polyline[index].Distance();
        map.setCenter(polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0));

        poly2[index] = new google.maps.Polyline({path: [polyline[index].getPath().getAt(0)], strokeColor:"#FFFF00", strokeWeight:3});

        timerHandle[index] = setTimeout("animate("+index+",50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------    



</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="tools">

    <button onclick="setRoutes();">Start</button>

</div>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear `makeRouteCallback is not defined`.  Are you sure it is in scope where it is used?  Hard to tell given the way you have broken your code up in the post.  Do you have a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: ok i am seeing the problem makeRouteCallback is a call back function within SetRoutes(). I will modify my code, however i am interested in extending the polyline once the marker reaches the end of the polyline. Can you advise me on that. Thank you

Comment: @geocodezip i updated the question and included a jsbin demo of similar code. I also included a description of what i want to achieve in the test code.

Comment: @geocodezip i attempted some updates on my code however i am not getting the polyline destination to change.

Comment: @geocodezip can you assist with this i am just not getting this to work.

Comment: @geocodezip i cam up with a different approach to my issue however i would liek to know how i can clear the overlays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish that doing the following :

First off, in `setRoutes()`, call the Directions renderer suppressing polylines (you are already drawing your own) :

```
 var rendererOptions = {
          map: map,
          suppressMarkers : true,
          suppressPolylines : true,
          preserveViewport: true
      }
```

Then in `animate()` set all markers and polylines to hidden when the route is over :

```
   if (d>eol[index]) {
        marker[index].setVisible(false);
        polyline[index].setVisible(false);
         poly2[index].setVisible(false);
         marker[index].setPosition(endLocation[index].latlng);
         return;
      }
```

Find your modified example here : [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/exApebI/1/)

Comment: could you also show me how i would approach it if i had to wait until all markers complete animation. If i have 'if(completed == startLoc.length){}' which once true represents the completion of the movement of all markers. I am attempting this. I create a loop and iterated setting marker and polyline.setVisible(false) and outside the loop i placed the return statement. However only the markers get cleared the polylines stay.